# How to get label text using ID of label stored in var with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need to get the label text of an Asp label and display in in an popup message.  Every label on the form has a key part of the ID identical to the key part of a text box.  I search the form for the text box, get the key value of the textbox ID , then construct the label ID and store that data in a var.  I then want to get the text of the label to use in my popup message.  Thus far I have this:

```
$(":input").each(function(){
    var key = $(this).attr('name');
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (key.toUpperCase().indexOf("TXTDYNAMIC_") >= 0) {
        alert("Found " + key + " looking for the associated label.");
        var arr = key.split('_');
        var labelid = "lblDynamic_" + arr[1] + ".ClientID" ;
        var labeltext = $('labelid').text();
    }
});
```

I get the textbox ID just fine, now I need to put the key part with the text "lblDynamic_" and then retrieve the label text.  I can't seem to get the `var labelid` variable such that I can display the label text.  I get a null string.  Each text box is identified with "txtDynamic_" and a unique key string, the associated label has the same unique key preceded with "lblDynamic_".  Any suggestions?

Comment: You talk about the ID of an element, but the jquery says `var key = $(this).attr('name');`, should that not be `var key = $(this).attr('id');`? And if this is not the issue, can you show a bit of the textbox and label html?

Comment: That particular line of code gets what I'm looking for, I split on the underscore and get the key string that is also part of the label name (or ID).  I can concatenate the label name (ID if you prefer) and store it in a var.  I need to use that var to find the label text.  Everything I've tried thus far has failed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you want to select the text box first, and then the label. Since you have a naming convention, then just select the labels based on their starting id by using a wildcard selector (select all labels starting with).

Say this markup:

```
        <asp:Label ID="lgroup1" runat="server" Text="Label 1"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ltext1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="lgroup2" runat="server" Text="Label 2"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ltext2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="lgroup3" runat="server" Text="Label 3"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ltext3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="test"
            OnClientClick="getlabels();return false"
            />


        <script>

            function getlabels() {

                var LabelList = $('[id^=lgroup]')

                LabelList.each(function () {
                    alert($(this).text())
                })

            }
```

So, above of course shows this:

[image]

Now above assumes no master page, or say a panel, since in those cases, then all controls are automatic prefixed with the page class, or panel name.

I suppose one could select all the text boxes "starting with" some prefix in the id but since the labels have a name that "starts with", then just do the jQuery selecting against the labels as above shows.

I suppose we could select the checkboxes and then build up a array of label "id" using this:

```
            function getlabels() {

                var TextBoxList = $('[id^=ltext]')
                var LabelList = []

                TextBoxList.each(function () {
                    LabelList.push( $(this).attr('id').replace("ltext","lgroup") )
                })

                LabelList.forEach(function (myitem) {
                    alert(myitem)
                })
            }
```

Or, I suppose, now that we have a simple array list of "id", then say this:

```
            function getlabels() {

                var TextBoxList = $('[id^=ltext]')
                var LabelList = []

                TextBoxList.each(function () {
                    LabelList.push( $(this).attr('id').replace("ltext","lgroup") )
                })

                LabelList.forEach(function (myitem) {

                    alert("label id = " + myitem + " text of label = " + $('#' + myitem).text())
                })
            }
```

Comment: Every label on the page is named "lblDynamic_" with a unique string following each underscore so the label can be uniquely identified, when I executed the code: `var LabelList = $('[id^=lblDynamic_]')`, nothing is returned.  Tried `var LabelList = $('[name^=lblDynamic_]')`, same result.  Given that all the information regarding dynamic labels/textboxes is stored in the database, I just execute an ajax call to the database and got what I needed that way.  But I'd certainly would rather not have the trip to the database.  Keep in mind all labels are asp labels.

Comment: Ah ... the line `var LabelList = $('[id*=lblDynamic_]')` returns all the labels with the prefix `lblDynamic_` on the page.  Note the asterick.  Given that I've already solved my issue with a call to the database, I'm leaving that in place.  Doesn't seem to impact performance at all.

Comment: Actually, you need to let the page render, hit f12 for browser debug tools,click on elements and then select the label in question. * is wild card. So, for starts with, you use ^ (https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and ends with is a $ (https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) -- So my guess is this is on a master page, or a nested element of such some, and asp.net will then inject it's own prevfix. If just a few controls, then add ClientIDMode="static" tag to each control, or view the element and include the starts with part you are missing.